# How can i difference between one and string and another one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I type a lot of words in an alert prompt, for example: "USB" but my error is when i tried to compare with the same string but in lower case, if i type "usb" how can i compare with "USB" and sent an alert that saids, "The string is the same", i do the same but when the first letter is in uppercase for example "Hello" and "hello", but how can i compare if my string is completely in uppercase?

i tried to do this

```
var res = document.getElementById("answer").value;
var resp = res.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ res.slice(1);

if(respuesta == textoALT.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ textoALT.slice(1))
alert("bla bla");
```

Comment: Simply convert both of them in same case.

Comment: Why use charAt? just toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() to uppercase or lowercase the full statement.

Comment: I think you might be confusing comparison with assignment.  Your if statement isn't assigning anything, so you should be able to convert both of the strings to upper or lower case and compare.  You don't need the charAt(0), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(respuesta.toLowerCase() == textoALT.toLowerCase()) {
// do something
```

Comment: It compares the lowercase equivalent of each string.

Comment: It's always a good idea to include an explanation of what your code does and why it solves the users problem, rather than just sticking in a line or two of code. It also helps stop your answers being flagged by the system as Low Quality, as this one was.

Answer (score 0):

Given two strings, `a` and `b`:

```
if (a === b) {
  // the strings are the same text in the same case
}
if (a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()) {
  // the strings are the same text but in a different case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in in 2 ways:

a) case sensitive

```
if (a === b) {
  // the strings are the same text in the same case
}
```

Remember to use `===` operator, as it means that a and b are same type and value.

Operator `==` will compare only values.

b) case insensitive  - check if both values are given

```
if (
    (a && b) && // optionally to ensure both values are defined:)
    (a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase())
   ) {
  // the strings are the same text but in a different case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to use charAt. you can use toUpperCase()

```
var str = "USB";
var str1 = "usb";
alert((str==str1.toUpperCase()));
```

For general Purpose.

```
alert((str.toUpperCase()==str1.toUpperCase()));
```

That will return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()) {
    // strings match regardless of case
}
```

Note, you should almost always use "===" instead of "==". "===" tests whether something's value and data type (number, string, boolean, object, etc.) matches another, whereas "==" only tests whether the values match (after performing a type conversion). For example:

```
if ("42" == 42) { // true
if ("42" === 42) { // false
```